# GET request from ESP-01 client to pushingbox doesn't work - 400 bad request

Tags: esp8266

I have my ESP-01 connected to a USB-to-TTL converter and I send AT commands through Terminal (by bray).

What I want to do is to put the esp-01 into client mode, then connect to pushingbox and finally send a GET request with my deviceID (API) to pushingbox. Then a notification will come to my android through my newtifry account.

I have tested the pushingbox scenarios from my PC and newtifry notifications comes to my android as expected.
Also when I type the url with my deviceID ( http://api.pushingbox.com/pushingbox?devid=xxxxxxxxxx ) in the address bar it works fine.

BUT when I try to do the same thing with esp-01, when I send the get request I receive a 400 Bad request (Your browser sent an invalid request). I changed the GET request format several times but the same thing happens.

I believe that the GET request I send is incomplete somehow but I cannot figure out what is missing.

Note: Terminal doesn't recognize \r and \n as single byte characters ( so \r\n = 4 bytes ===> one for each character \ r \ n). So the URL string I send is the number of URL characters + 4 bytes for every \r\n in the string.
For example if the URL string is 88 characters (bytes) long with \r\n\r\n in the end I add 8 characters.

Below I display the exact sequence of commands I send every time and also the different versions of the GET request I have tried to send so far with no success.

AT+CWMODE=1
AT+CWJAP="SSID","pswd"
AT+CIPSTART="TCP","api.pushingbox.com",80
AT+CIPMODE=0
AT+CIPSEND= number of characters of the GET request (bytes)

GET /pushingbox?devid=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: api.pushingbox.com\r\n\r\n

GET /pushingbox?devid=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: api.pushingbox.com\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n

GET /pushingbox?devid=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: api.pushingbox.com\r\nUser-Agent: ESP8266\r\n\r\n

GET /pushingbox?devid=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: api.pushingbox.com\r\nUser-Agent: ESP8266\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n

GET /pushingbox?devid=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: api.pushingbox.com\r\nUser-Agent: ESP8266\r\nContent-Type: text/html\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n

GET /pushingbox?devid=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Note: Terminal doesn't recognize \r and \n as single byte characters ( so \r\n = 4 bytes ===> one for each character \ r \ n). So the URL string I send is the number of URL characters + 4 bytes for every \r\n in the string. For example if the URL string is 88 characters (bytes) long with \r\n\r\n in the end I add 8 characters.

You've hit the problem though your solution is wrong. Your solution sends the ASCII value for each character in `\r\n`, taking the slashes not as part of an escape sequence but as separate characters in their own right. You're sending 4 bytes: `92, 114, 92, 110` instead of 2 bytes: `13, 10`. You cant type these escape sequences in your textbox (which takes everything literally) so you'll need to get the terminal program to do it for you. I'm not familiar with Terminal; I think you have to set up `\r\n` as transmit macros. But this is really easy to do with the Arduino serial monitor. Just set the Line Ending to 'Both NL & CR' and each time you press Enter to send a string, `\r\n` will be appended automatically. So you need only type:

```
GET /pushingbox?devid=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx HTTP/1.1
```

and press Enter once. Subsequent lines can be sent in a similar manner; simply press Enter as many times as you need `\r\n`.

Most serial monitoring programs have this feature, you just have to figure out how to set it up.

Comment: Yes you are correct, It worked! Thank you TisteAndii